# How to expand video box and center it on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to take a div element with a video element inside of it that when hovered on will transform (scale) the video box twice it's size and center it. I also have it to where when I hover over the video element it auto plays the clip. What I currently have won't expand the box at all. I'm using react.

````
```
    const playVideo = () => {
    const videoBox = window.document.getElementById("video-clip");
    videoBox.play();
    videoBox.style.transition = "transform 1.5s";
    videoBox.style.transform = "scale(2, 2)";
    videoBox.style.marginLeft = "300px";
}
const stopVideo = () => {
    const videoBox = window.document.getElementById("video-clip");
    videoBox.load();
    videoBox.style.transition = "transform 1.5s";
    videoBox.style.transform = "scale(1, 1)";
    videoBox.style.marginLeft = "";
}
return (
    <div>
        <div id="comicbook-action" onClick={handleClick} style={{ cursor: "pointer", width: "320px", height: "240px" }}>
            <video onMouseEnter={playVideo} onMouseLeave={stopVideo} id="video-clip" width="320" height="240" poster={poster} autoplay>
                <source src={clip} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using React, that's the not the correct way to change styles in HTML elements. Since it doesn't re-render the component.
Try changing styles by changing state instead.
For example:

```
// If you're using functional components and not classes
const [videoStyles, setVideoStyles] = useState({
   transition: "all 1.5s",
   transform: "scale(2, 2)",
   marginLeft: "300px"
});    

const playVideo = e => {
    e.target.play();
    setVideoStyles({
        transform: "scale(2, 2)",
        marginLeft: "300px"
    });
}
const stopVideo = e => {
    e.target.pause();
    setVideoStyles({
        transform: "scale(1, 1)",
        marginLeft: 0
    });
}
return (
    <div>
        <div id="comicbook-action" onClick={handleClick} style={{ cursor: "pointer", width: "320px", height: "240px" }}>
            <video onMouseEnter={playVideo} onMouseLeave={stopVideo} width="320" height="240" poster={poster} style={videoStyles} autoplay>
                <source src={clip} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

I hope you get the idea here